# NativeScript Throwing Error Response with status: 200 for URL: null

Tags: json, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular4-httpclient, nativescript-angular

I am using Angular4 with TypeScript version 2.2.2

My web app is running fine when I call JSON with Filters but my NativeScript app fails when I call the Filter Values as an Object but works fine when I call filter values as a string.

Error Response with status: 200 for URL: null

THIS WORKS
https://domainname.com/api/v1/searchevents?token=057001a78b8a7e5f38aaf8a682c05c414de4eb20&filter=text&search=upcoming

If the filter value and search value is STRING it works whereas if they are objects as below, it does not work

THIS DOES NOT WORK

https://api.domainname.com/api/v1/searchevents?token=057001a78b8a7e5f38aaf8a682c05c414de4eb20&filter={"limit":"12","skip":"0"}&search={"search":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","categories":"","address":"","type":"upcoming"}

The Code I used is below

getData(serverUrl, type, skip_limit) {

```
    console.log(serverUrl);
    let headers = this.createRequestHeader();
    let token_value = localStorage.getItem('access_token')

    let url;
    var filter;

    filter = '{"limit":"10","skip":"0"}'



    url = this.apiUrl + serverUrl + '?token=' + token_value + '&filter=' + filter

    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

The URL as formed above for the API is fine and works fine. Yet the error comes Error Response with status: 200 for URL: null

CAN ANYONE HELP ME SOLVE THIS?

Comment: If I add Filter Value as a String it is working but does NOT work if we add filter value as an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is the "filter" values are of different type and from what you mentioned as what worked, your service is expecting a string and not an object/array. So it fails to send the proper response when it gets one. With an object in the URL, you may have to rewrite the service to read it as an object (parse the two attributes and get them individually)

To make it simple, you can make these two as two different variables in the URL. like below,

```
https://api.domainName.in/api/v1/oauth/token?limit=10&skip=0
```

Be more precise in whats happening in your question,

1) Log the exact URL and post it in the question. No one can guess what goes in "text" in your first URL.

2) Your URL which you mentioned as worked have "token" as part of path, but in the code, its a variable which will have a dynamic value from "token_value".

3) Post your service code. Especially the signature and input parsing part.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:
All you have to do is encode the Filter and Search Parameters if it is an Object or Array using Typescript encodeURI()

var filter = '{"limit":"12","skip":"0"}'

var search = '{"search":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","categories":"","address":"","type":"upcoming"}'

var encoded_filter = encodeURI(filter);

var encoded_search = encodeURI(search);

url = this.apiUrl+serverUrl+'?token='+token_value+'&filter='+encoded_filter+'&search='+encoded_search